# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{x^{100}}$ without l'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm quite at a loss. I would 'expect' it to be equal to $1$ since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}2\sin(3x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \Big (\cfrac{\sin x}{x^{10}} \Big)^{10} = 1?$

Hints please! (Preferably not the full answer)

Comment: You need to use $$\lim_{\text{Arc}\to0}\frac{\sin(\text{Arc})}{\text{Arc}}=1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}3x)}{x^{10}}\right)^{10}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}3x)}{2\sin^{10}3x}\lim_{x\to0}2\cdot 3^{10}\left(\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^{10}\right)^{10}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{x^{100}} = \left(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{x^{10}}\right)^{10},
$$
so it suffices to evaluate the limit within the power. Now
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{x^{10}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{2\sin^{10}(3x)} \frac{2\sin^{10}(3x)}{x^{10}}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{2\sin^{10}(3x)} \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\sin^{10}(3x)}{x^{10}},
$$
and the first part of this product is just 1. So we are looking for 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\sin^{10}(3x)}{x^{10}} = 2\left(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\right)^{10}.
$$
Finally this innermost limit equals
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \times 3 = 3.
$$
Working back, we see that your answer is $$2^{10}3^{100} = 527746581229579602981336196879996183246958102529024.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the leading terms:
$$\sin 3x = 3x + \frac{3^3}{3!}x^3 + \cdots$$
$$2\sin^{10}3x = 2(3x + \frac{3^3}{3!}x^3 + \cdots)^{10} = 2\cdot 3^{10}x^{10} + \cdots$$
$$\sin(2\sin^{10}3x) = (2\cdot 3^{10}x^{10} + \cdots) + \frac{1}{3!}(2\cdot 3^{10}x^{10} + \cdots)^3 + \cdots=2\cdot 3^{10}x^{10} + \cdots$$
$$\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}3x)=(2\cdot 3^{10}x^{10} + \cdots)^{10} = 2^{10}3^{100}x^{100}+\cdots$$
$$\frac{\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}3x)}{x^{100}}=\frac{2^{10}3^{100}x^{100}+\cdots}{x^{100}}=2^{10}3^{100}+\cdots$$

All of the "$\cdots$" terms involve higher powers of $x$ which will disappear in the limit. So
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}3x)}{x^{100}} = \boxed{2^{10}3^{100}}.$$

Comment: @Bernard : What does that mean? Are you saying that you downvoted?

Comment: Not at all (I never downvote). I also was downvoted for my own answer, and am recurrently, always without any explanation.

Comment: @Bernard : Okay, I understand. Yes, morons like that seem to run rampant here. If I think an answer is wrong, I would certainly comment on why I think that so the author can try either to explain it or to correct it. Downvoting has the specific meaning of “This answer is not useful” which clearly is not the case in most instances where I’ve been downvoted. I sometimes downvote, but only if the answer is blatantly in error, and always with an explanation—and will remove the downvote if the answer is subsequently corrected

Answer (score 0):

As often, the most straightforward way is via *equivalents*: as $\sin u\sim_0 u$, we have
$$\frac{\sin^{10}(2\sin^{10}(3x))}{x^{100}}\sim_0\frac{\sin^{10}(2(3x)^{10})}{x^{100}}\sim_0\frac{\bigl(2(3x)^{10}\bigr)^{10}}{x^{100}}=\frac{2^{10}3^{100}\not x^{100}}{\not x^{100}}=2^{10}3^{100}.$$